# How to set custom resolution with xrandr and .xprofile?

Tags: display, display-resolution, xrandr

I've been trying for two days already to set the native resolution of my monitor in xubuntu. I had to install linux kernel 4.10 for it to start xfce.
I run these commands in my .xprofile:

```
xrandr --newmode "1600x900_60.00"  118.25  1600 1696 1856 2112  900 903 908 934 -hsync +vsync
xrandr --addmode DP2 1600x900_60.00
xrandr --output DP2 --mode 1600x900_60.00
```

But at booting time it launches the error:

```
xrandr: Output DP1 is not disconnected but has no modes
xrandr: Output HDMI1 is not disconnected but has no modes
xrandr: Output HDMI2 is not disconnected but has no modes
xrandr: Output HDMI3 is not disconnected but has no modes
xrandr: Output DP1 is not disconnected but has no modes
xrandr: Output HDMI1 is not disconnected but has no modes
xrandr: Output HDMI2 is not disconnected but has no modes
xrandr: Output HDMI3 is not disconnected but has no modes
xrandr: Output DP1 is not disconnected but has no modes
xrandr: Output HDMI1 is not disconnected but has no modes
xrandr: Output HDMI2 is not disconnected but has no modes
xrandr: Output HDMI3 is not disconnected but has no modes
```

Which I think is one for each command in the .xprofile.
Adding this command does not help neither.

```
xrandr --output HDMI1 --off --output HDMI2 --off --output HDMI3 --off --output DP1 --off
```

Programs like lxrandr or arandr always ended up making xfce not booting and not letting me do anything, not even change the tty.

This is my xrandr output:

```
eDP1 connected 1024x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 0mm x 0mm
   1024x768      60.00*+
   800x600       60.32    56.25  
   640x480       59.94  
   512x384       60.00  
DP1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP2 connected 1024x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 0mm x 0mm
   1024x768      60.00* 
   800x600       60.32    56.25  
   848x480       60.00  
   640x480       59.94  
HDMI1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
VIRTUAL1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

My hardware is:
    - Asus H170 gaming pro
    - Intel Core I7 7700
    - Hyper X DDR4 8Gb 2400MHz

Thanks for reading this far.